# tinyMCE script error `A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding

Tags: javascript, jsp, tinymce, textarea

when I use tinyMCE editor in my jsp page, Script Error occur during loading time  . The error is,

`A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
Script:  .............../js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js:4 '

following is the fragment for TinyMCE I use in the .jsp

```
<script>
var text = tinymce.DOM.decode('<%=txt.trim()%>');
tinymce.init({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector : "report_txt_area",
        entity_encoding : "raw",
        readonly : 1,
    inline: false,
    statusbar : false,
    toolbar: false,
    menubar: false,
    plugins : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "",
    init_instance_callback : function(){tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(tinymce.DOM.decode(text), {format : 'raw'})}
});

var textNotSaved = tinymce.DOM.decode('<%=txtNotSaved.trim()%>');
tinymce.init({
        mode : "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector : "detailedReportText",
        entity_encoding : "raw",
    inline: false,
    statusbar : false,
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent",
    menubar: false,
    plugins : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "",
    init_instance_callback : function(){tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(tinymce.DOM.decode(textNotSaved), {format : 'raw'})}
});

</script>
```

the page has 2 text areas and  report_txt_area is a readonly field.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its resolved now . It was bad data causing this . My mistake
The text area is preloaded with some content & included some special characters which caused the script to error .
Answering the question so nobody wastes their time on this. Thanks for reading.